# window size have locked, after system update

Tags: linux, fedora, resolution

I'm using linux fedora35. the rison why I've started my linux experience is the same problem i've got now. display settings on my laptop locked on 800X600 and would not change no matter what. skreen standard resolution was 1920X1080.
When I encountered this problem on windows i didn't find any solution and so I bailed on linux. Linux haven't had any problems before last update where it all broke

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages indicate you have an AMD Radeon "Picasso" GPU, which was released in 2019.

A common reason for the "resolution getting locked to 800x600" on upgrade could be that your latest update included a newer kernel but no corresponding newer version of proprietary GPU driver (most likely the "AMDGPU Pro" driver) you had been using until the update. The open-source driver ("AMDGPU" without the "Pro" suffix) would not have this problem, as it's included in the standard kernel packages.

(Whenever using any sort of third-party drivers with Linux, there is always a risk that when there's a kernel update, the third-party driver does not get updated as quickly as the kernel, and you must either live without the functionality until the driver is also updated to match the kernel, or run a previous kernel until the updated driver is also available.)

The lack of a correct AMD GPU driver would force the display subsystem to fall back to firmware-provided framebuffer interfaces (if legacy BIOS, the relevant driver might be `vesafb`; the UEFI firmware would have `efifb`). These firmware-provided interfaces have no acceleration features at all, and usually the resolution will be locked to whatever the firmware has initially set.

Try selecting the previous kernel in the GRUB boot menu: I don't have an example of Fedora 35 at hand, but if its GRUB installation follows the usual pattern, you'll first need to select the second option from the top, titled something like "Advanced options for Fedora". This will open a sub-menu of all kernel versions you currently have installed (the package management system will normally keep the newest kernel and one or two older versions as backups), and each kernel version will have a normal boot option and a recovery mode option.

In this specific situation, you would want the previous kernel in normal boot mode: that would usually be the third menu item from the top in the "Advanced options for..." submenu.

If booting with the previous kernel version fixes the resolution issue, the real fix will depend on exactly how you originally installed the proprietary AMDGPU Pro driver.

The simplest possibility is if you used a RPM-packaged version of the driver from some third-party repository: in that case, as soon as the maintainer of that repository provides an updated driver package for Fedora 35's newest kernel version, your package management tool should automatically detect it and offer it for installation. You might also want to install the `dkms` package: it provides an automated way for third-party drivers to be locally rebuilt to match the newest kernel if pre-packaged versions are not yet available.

If you installed the "AMDGPU Pro" RPM packages manually, you might have to reinstall them every time a kernel update gets installed, or to read the driver documentation to figure out the necessary commands to "refresh" the existing driver installation for the newest kernel, and remember to repeat those steps every time a new kernel RPM is installed for any reason.